# Issues with Pycharm not finding packages

Tags: python, pycharm

I am having multiple issues running a code in pycharm. Since I am a student and I am using copyright protected code, I cannot share it here, but I can assure you, it is not code related.

Whenever I try to run the code, I get the following errors:

```
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`
```

I have already installed numpy for python 3.8 and it also shows up in the package interpreter, but Pycharm keeps trying to run my code in `/usr/bin/python3.7` for some reason, even tho I have my system interpreter set to Python 3.8.

I've also tried running the code with venv in 3.8. Still the same error.

Now when I try to set my interpreter to Python 3.7, both as System Interpreter and venv, I get that numpy is not installed.

When I try to install numpy specifying Python 3.7:

```
/usr/bin/python3.7 -m pip install numpy
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
```

I've tried to install distutils.util, but I keep getting the same error message.

Is there something wrong with Python 3.7? Is there a way of telling pycharm not to run in Python 3.7?

I would also like to add that I've already tried reinstalling everything from scratch, including Ubuntu.

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: First thing you need to do is to have a single python version whether its 3.8 or 3.7, multiple version installation may cause these type of error. And also delete all the virtual environment as well.

Comment: After that go to pycharm settings, then select project after that select project interpreter and then search for you packages, if packages is not present then click on + to add packages. Then do pycharm changes in its skeleton then try to run your project.

Comment: If your problem isn't solve then let me know. I will give you screen shots or some video link.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, I managed to solve the issue now by deleting all interpreters and setting them up from scratch.

There probably was some sort of conflict between multiple interpreters and different python versions